# docker run/start: Is there a significant impact on disk space by using the "run" command over and over?

Tags: docker

I'm wondering what is the best practice for launching many containers (on the order of thousands per day) in terms of using `docker container run` or `docker container start`. I realize that `start` is used on a stopped container and `run` would be used to create a new container, but does it matter which one is used if the same underlying image is used across all the containers?

My guess is that since all the containers use the same image there would be very little overhead for creating many thousands of containers. In other words, just use `docker container run` over and over again.

Should I instead try to search for an existing container before starting a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to pass `--rm` to `docker run`. This will cause the container to be deleted as soon as it's done running, so repeated calls to it won't keep using more and more space.